# pass entityManager to EntityType class

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

Using Symfony 3.2, I would pass entityManager object to EntityType class through constructor.

I found that it can been done using services, as my configuration below:

config.yml

> ```
> imports:
>     - { resource: parameters.yml }
>     - { resource: security.yml }
>     - { resource: services.yml }
>     - { resource: "@mybundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
> ```

services.yml

> ```
> services:
>     mybundle.profile_key:
>         class: App\Bundle\mybundle\Form\ProfileKeyType
>         arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
> ```

My EntityType:

```
namespace App\Bundle\mybundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ProfileKeyType extends AbstractType
{

    private $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('key', TextType::class, array(
                "label" => "Chiave identificativa"
        ))->add('visible', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label' => "Default visible",
                "label_attr" => array( 'title' => 'Imposta la visibilit&agrave; di default di questa chiave' ),
                'required' => true
        ))->add('entity', CollectionType::class, array(
                "data_class" => Entity::class
        ))->add('property')->add('type');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Bundle\mybundle\Entity\ProfileKey'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_mybundle_profilekey';
    }


}
```

When I lauch my insert page, I get this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Bundle\myBundle\Form\ProfileKeyType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\eclipse_neon_workspace\iSerPa\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 85
```

What's wrong??

Thx in advance

Comment: it is a typing problem, the type used in the argument is not the type imported by `use` statement probably.

Comment: Do you mean that object used in ProfileKeyType "use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" is not the same as passed through services.yml??

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, but what I see is `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` is representing `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` which is weird. Please to try with another entityManager if you have it

Comment: a) Clear your cache if you haven't already done so. b) Post the controller using that FormType, make sure you're not trying to instantiate that class directly yourself. (eg. through createForm with the class name, use the service name in that case)

Answer (score 2):

When creating the form, you can simply do like this :

```
// inside controller action
// $em is the required EntityManager instance
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$form = $this->createForm(new ProfileKeyType($em), $profileKey);
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, I have seen this solution in other discussions,
but I've always thought it as a workaround. I believe injection is the best solution, but if it does not work, I guess I'll turn on your solution.  Rgds

Comment: Hi, if you want to use injection, you can get your formType instance like another service in symfony, I mean with :
$form = $this->get('mybundle.profile_key');

Comment: Sorry Stephan, do you mean that, into my ProfileKeyType, I must get the ProfileKeyType from $this->get("serpabackendbundle.profile_key")??
I think this is a no sense code, because I need entity_manager inside my ProfileKeyType for create property type field with select element and related Entities options

Comment: No, I mean that when you create your form in controller, if you don't want to use new ProfileKeyType($em), you can get formType with : $formType =  $this->get("serpabackendbundle.profile_key"), then create your form with : $form = $this->createForm($formType, $entity)

Comment: Ah ok Stephan, I will try it! Thx

Answer (score 0):

you should add the form.type tag to your service definition like this:

```
services:
serpabackend.profile_key:
    class: App\Bundle\mybundle\Form\ProfileKeyType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: Not solved!
Only thing symfony require me is to change class from

class: App\Bundle\mybundle\Form\ProfileKeyType

to 

class: Appmybundle\Form\ProfileKeyType

but error is the same:

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Bundle\myBundle\Form\ProfileKeyType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\eclipse_neon_workspace\iSerPa\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 85

Comment: How are you creating the form ?

Comment: With CRUD utility, in the generated controller ProfileKeyController


        $profileKey = new Profilekey();
        $form = $this->createForm('App\Bundle\myBundle\Form\ProfileKeyType', $profileKey);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

....

        return $this->render('profilekey/new.html.twig', array(
            'profileKey' => $profileKey,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

Comment: Try getting the service in controller and see if you get an error with
$this->get('serpabackend.profile_key');

you can also check if your service is loaded correctly with

bin/console |grep "serpabackend.profile_key"

Comment: Left out part of the console command.  bin/console debug:container serpabackend And yes it sure seems like the service is not being created.  I suppose you try clearing the cache as well though as long as you are in development mode it should not matter.

Comment: You can try moving the definition in app/config/services.yml

Comment: Ok Dan, I will try asap

Comment: No Dan...
I've tried getting$this->get("serpabackend.profile_key") in ProfileKeyController, and no errors occurs.
But, getting this service in constructor of ProfileKeyType, I have same error everytime: it seems that nothing was passed to ProfileKeyType constructor.
If I digit php bin\console, I find nothing about this service

Comment: Hi Cerad,
  typing your command php bin\console debug:container, in list I've found my service: serpabackend.profile_key                                             Serpa\Bundle\backendBundle\Form\ProfileKeyType.

I don't know why it's doesn't works